# Bamboo build: How to show more than 100 commits

Tags: build, bamboo, smart-commits

I read bamboo documentation but could not find the answer.  Is there a way to configure bamboo so that it shows more than 100 commits for each build.

Context:
We are trying to track which commits were deployed to Production. At the moment it displays 100 of XXXX only shown.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. Please have a look at [this issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-14145) in Atlassians JIRA, which is kind of ignored for over 2 years.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11624520)

Comment: Question "Is there a way to configure bamboo so that it shows more than 100 commits for each build." My answer (and the only possible): "That is not possible". And a link with further information. So where is the problem here?

Comment: I'm with epic_antihero, the answer to the question is that it is not possible. That is an extremely helpful answer for those hitting the same issue (as we just have). The link to the JIRA issue then provides further information. Your advice is incorrect.